# How to change Opt Out Link/URL in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have changed the folder name from sugarcrm to xyzcrm. Everything is working fine. But the opt out link is having the url sugarcrm instead of xyzcrm. Please let me know how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out config.php and look for the 'site_url' parameter. I bet it still shows 'sugarcrm' in the path.

config.php is in the SugarCRM root directory, probably something like /var/www/xyzcrm/config.php.